# How to redirect not created page to the created page in wordpress through .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect not created page to the created page in wordpress through .htaccess but it's not redirecting.I am using this code at the top of wordpress .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule http://www.myweb.com/fs http://www.myweb.com/services/first-service/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not match the entire URL but instead the path:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^fs$ /services/first-service/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Dear,
But its not working.Can you please tell me how can i check my .htaccess file working or not. I remove all code from my htaccess file but site also running in wordpress.